# How to compare dates in hibernate

Tags: java, spring, hibernate

In my Data base dates are as `2012-04-09 04:02:53` `2012-04-09 04:04:51` `2012-04-08 04:04:51`, etc, I need to retrieve data which have current date in there date field. I mean i need to match only `2012-04-09'` . How can i do it using hibernate criteria.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

Use [Restrictions.between()](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/core/3.6/javadocs/org/hibernate/criterion/Restrictions.html#between%28java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Object,%20java.lang.Object%29) to generate a where clause which the date column is between '2012-04-09 00:00:00' and '2012-04-09 23:59:59'

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss");
Date fromDate = df.parse("2012-04-09 00:00:00");
Date toDate = df.parse("2012-04-09 23:59:59");

criteria.add(Restrictions.between("dateField", fromDate, toDate));
```

Please note that all the properties used in the Criteria API is the Java property name , but not the actual column name.

---

Update: Get fromDate and toDate for the current date using JDK only

```
Calendar calendar = Calendar.getInstance();
calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
Date fromDate = calendar.getTime();

calendar.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
calendar.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
calendar.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
Date toDate = calendar.getTime();

criteria.add(Restrictions.between("dateField", fromDate, toDate));
```

Comment: How to get fromDate and toDate from Currentdate

Comment: @Ken Chan Thank you so much buddy for posting date comparison of single date. I'll give you +1 for `23:59:59` in parse method.

Comment: This was helpful. I think hibernate should provide a function to compare date without time.

Comment: While this works for all practical purposes. 23:59:59 is still not exactly EOD. I would let java figure this out for me: LocalDate.now().atTime(LocalTime.MAX).atZone(ZoneId.systemDefault()).toInstant()

Answer (score 2):

Like this?

```
criteria.add(Expression.eq("yourDate", aDate))
```

Comment: How about using Expression.between("yourDate", aDate, aDate+1)

Comment: This didn't work for me , I think it does the exact much , the best case to compare dates is the first answer.

Answer (score 2):

```
fromDate.setTime(new Date());
fromDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
fromDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
fromDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
fromDate.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
```

This code is extremely dangerous ... if the day is switch to daylight saving time (e.g. 06.04.1980) you end up in following exception!!!

```
 java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: HOUR_OF_DAY: 0 -> 1day


HQL: from human pat where year(pat.birthdate) = :start_day and month(pat.birthdate) = :start_month and year(pat.birthdate) = :start_year ");

params.put("start_day", startDate.get(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH));
params.put("start_month", startDate.get(Calendar.MONTH) + 1);
params.put("start_year", startDate.get(Calendar.YEAR));
```

The year/month/day functions use the underlying db functions (extract, ...) and compares only these values. Therefore I did not need to set the time to 0 which leads to the above described exception.
just an example out of my mind how I solved the problem! Maybe it helps

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is to fetch all records having date between the beginning and end of a given day:

```
WHERE date BETWEEN :from AND :to
```

And compute `from` and `to` in your Java code.

For computing midnights:

```
import static org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils.ceiling;
import static org.apache.commons.lang.time.DateUtils.truncate;

Date someDay = new Date();
Date from = truncate(someDay, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH);
Date to = new Date(ceiling(someDay, Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH).getTime() - 1);
```

Comment: i dint get it. ceiling and truncate is for ?

Comment: @Romi: you need to somehow compute the beginning of a day (`Mon Apr 09 00:00:00 CEST 2012`) and the end of it (`Mon Apr 09 23:59:59 CEST 2012`).

Comment: @Romi: yes, truncate returns the beginning of a given day (00:00) and ceiling - the beginning of the next day.

Answer (score 1):

How-to do it in Hibernate has already been said. You can prepare the `Timestamp` objects in the Java code using, for example, the following aproach:

```
Calendar cFrom = Calendar.getInstance();
cFrom.setTime(new Date()); /* today */
cFrom.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
cFrom.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
cFrom.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
cFrom.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);
Timestamp from = new Timestamp(cFrom.getTime().getTime());
Calendar cTo = Calendar.getInstance();
cTo.setTime(new Date()); /* today */
cTo.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
cTo.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
cTo.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
cTo.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999);
Timestamp to = new Timestamp(cTo.getTime().getTime());

final String QUERY = ""
  + "SELECT tr "
  + "FROM Type tr "
  + "WHERE tr.timestamp >= :timestampFrom AND tr.timestamp <= :timestampTo";
Query query = entityManager.createQuery(QUERY);
query.setParameter("timestampFrom", from);
query.setParameter("timestampTo", to);
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
List<Type> ts = (List<Type>)query.getResultList();
```

Answer (score 0):

```
Restrictions.between("dateColumn", midnight1, midnight2)
```

Answer (score 0):

```
The following code will work

Calendar fromDate = Calendar.getInstance();
fromDate.setTime(new Date());
fromDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 0);
fromDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 0);
fromDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, 0);
fromDate.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 0);

Calendar toDate = Calendar.getInstance();
toDate.setTime(new Date());
toDate.set(Calendar.HOUR_OF_DAY, 23);
toDate.set(Calendar.MINUTE, 59);
toDate.set(Calendar.SECOND, 59);
toDate.set(Calendar.MILLISECOND, 999);

criteria.add(Restrictions.between("loadDate", fromDate.getTime(),
                    toDate.getTime()));
```

Answer (score 0):

// datetime comparison Hibernate 4.3

```
     Select c from Customer c where c.date<{d '2000-01-01'}
```