# Hibernate. Check if daterange is within another daterange

Tags: java, hibernate

This sounds pretty simple, but i just cant wrap my head around it.

I have two fields in my DB. availableFromDate and availableToDate.

The user is doing a search to find all entities available within a given range. So my action receives two dates:

searchFromDate and searchToDate.

All i need to do is to return all entities that is available the whole period specified by the user.

Preferably using Criterias.

Anyone?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand you question correctly - That is, that the event availability should lie completely within the search date range - then it should boil down to this:

If you ensure that "availableFromDate.before(availableToDate)" and "searchFromDate.before(searchToDate)" - which you should do anyway in this case - Then both your availableFromDate and your availableToDate have to be in the search date range.

You can use the solution from this answer to make sure both dates are within the range: [How to compare dates in hibernate](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073893/how-to-compare-dates-in-hibernate)

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.between("availableFromDate", searchFromDate, searchToDate));
criteria.add(Restrictions.between("availableToDate", searchFromDate, searchToDate));
```

Comment: Thanks for your contribution David! You almost got it right. It is just the other way around. The search date-range must be completly within the availability. In other words, i only want to return those entities that are at least available the entire search-range.