# SQL TIMESTAMP Column and Java TimeStamp/Date Comparision

Tags: java, sql

I have a date object in format "Wed Feb 12 00:11:29 GMT 2014" and I have TIMESTAMP column in DB. I want a query records from the table which are greater than the date given in Java Program. I am using ">=" operator to compare. But it's not comparing properly. I mean it will compare day wise properly but not based on Hours properly.

```
Date d= new Date("Wed Feb 12 00:11:29 GMT 2014");
String qry="select * from table where date_comlum >=?";
st.setTimestamp(1,d.getTime());
st.execute(qry);
```

Comment: why cant you use timestamp instead of date? Timestamp timestamp =  new Timestamp(new Date("Wed Feb 12 00:11:29 GMT 2014").getTime());

Comment: I have tried this too. But Same result :(       "stmt.setTimestamp(  1, new java.sql.Timestamp( ((Date) "Wed Feb 12 00:11:29 GMT 2014").getTime() ) );"

Comment: Possibly duplicate of this [How to compare dates in hibernate][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10073893/how-to-compare-dates-in-hibernate

Comment: @Sonal:-      But that is different case.

Comment: Can any one suggest me is there any other way to compare timestamp other than ">=" operator?

Comment: Can Anyone suggest any other approach? Hour wise it's not comparing

Answer (score 0):

Use below mentioned.

```
select * from TableA
where startdate >= to_timestamp('12-01-2012 21:24:00', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
  and startdate <= to_timestamp('12-01-2012 21:25:33', 'dd-mm-yyyy hh24:mi:ss')
```

Comment: Hey I have tried this Solution. But When I execute in SQL Prompt query will execute properly. But not through Java Program!!

Comment: Use DateTimeFormat or SimpleDateFormat of Java to pass the date objects. For more information about it please check http://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_date_time.htm

Comment: Hey I have tried formats but it also. I will give to examples.