# How to access multiple tables in a single query using Hibernate Criteria?

Tags: java, hibernate, criteria

I have two tables to query, and so far I've come up with the following HQL-query:

```
From DriverEntity d 
where exists (
    From LicenceEntity l 
    where driverId = d.Id 
        and l.licenceType.id = '3'
        and l.validFrom > TO_DATE('2014-01-01', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
        and l.validFrom < TO_DATE('2014-04-17', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
        and l.validTo > TO_DATE('2014-07-02', 'YYYY-MM-DD')
        and l.validTo < TO_DATE('2095-07-12', 'YYYY-MM-DD')))
```

I'm querying two tables; one with licences and one with drivers. Each driver can have many licences.

The query works perfectly, but I would like to use Criteria instead to make it easier to edit when I add more search options.

What would this query look like using Criteria? I've looked into DetachedCriteria, but I don't understand it completely.

Comment: What have you tried? StackOverflow is a site for asking specific questions where you've tried something and have a problem. General "How do I do this" questions with no attempts shown tend to have a bad time and are somewhat offtopic. Try something and then ask a specific question if you have a problem

Comment: As an aside, why use criteria? My personal experience has been they lead to fragmentation... I'll take HQL over criteria anyday =)

Comment: I want to use Criteria since I'm planning to add a lot more Restrictions, and the HQL-queries got very complicated after a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can add a the subquery with help of `DetachedCriteria`:

```
SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd");
Criteria criteria = Criteria.forClass(DriverEntity.class,"driver");
DetachedCriteria dc = DetachedCriteria.forClass(LicenceEntity.class,"licence");
dc.add(Property.forName("driver.id").eqProperty("licence.driverId"));
dc.add(Restrictions.between("validFrom", df.parse("2014-01-01"), df.parse("2014-04-17")));
dc.add(Restrictions.between("validTo", df.parse("2014-07-02"), df.parse("2095-07-12")));

criteria.add(Subqueries.exists(dc.setProjection(Projections.id())));
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `Restrictions` :

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.between("dateField", fromDate, toDate));
```

**For your query :**

```
criteria.add(Restrictions.between("validFrom", vFd1, vFd2));
criteria.add(Restrictions.between("validTo", vTd1, vTd2));
```

Where

vFd1,2 and vTd1,2 will be java calender dates with time set to zero.

**Ref :**

https://stackoverflow.com/a/10074111/3603806

Answer (score 0):

according to [Hibernate Developer Guide](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html_single/#d5e3306) the developers should use CriteriaQuery instead of Criteria.

Look at this example thats explains how to create a [multiple roots query or joins](http://docs.jboss.org/hibernate/orm/4.1/devguide/en-US/html_single/#d5e3464)